# How do I select a specific block of text in vim?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, vi

These are the contents in my file

```
-r-xr-xr-x 1 dinesh eng  29072 Aug 26  2004 config.sub
-r-xr-xr-x 1 dinesh eng  38515 Aug 26  2004 config.guess
-r-xr-xr-x 1 dinesh eng   5643 Aug 26  2004 install-sh
-r-xr-xr-x 1 dinesh eng    767 Aug 26  2004 mkinstalldirs
-r-xr-xr-x 1 dinesh eng   6328 Aug 26  2004 missing
-r-xr-xr-- 1 dinesh eng    440 Aug 27  2004 build.sh
-r--r--r-- 1 dinesh eng    975 Apr  2  2015 Makefile.am
-r--r--r-- 1 dinesh eng   1153 Apr  2  2015 configure.ac
-r-xr-xr-- 1 dinesh eng    952 Apr  2  2015 autogen.sh
drwxrwxr-x 4 dinesh eng   4096 Nov 30  2016 Scripts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dinesh eng     35 Dec  1  2016 ltmain.sh -> /usr/share/libtool/config/ltmain.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh eng   2801 Dec  1  2016 config.h.in
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dinesh eng     32 Dec  1  2016 depcomp -> /usr/share/automake-1.11/depcomp
drwxrwxr-x 7 dinesh eng   4096 Dec  1  2016 install
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh eng  41966 Feb 14 00:30 aclocal.m4
drwxr-xr-x 2 dinesh eng     81 Feb 14 00:30 autom4te.cache
-rwxrwxr-x 1 dinesh eng 606261 Feb 14 00:30 configure
drwxrwxr-x 3 dinesh eng   4096 Feb 14 00:30 bin
drwxrwxr-x 3 dinesh eng     53 Feb 14 00:30 preinstall
drwxrwxr-x 4 dinesh eng   4096 Feb 14 00:30 share
drwxrwxr-x 7 dinesh eng     97 Feb 14 00:30 test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh eng  26776 Feb 14 00:30 Makefile.in
drwxrwxr-x 9 dinesh eng   4096 Feb 14 00:31 build
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dinesh eng     10 Feb 14 00:35 stamp-h.in
drwxrwxr-x 3 dinesh eng   4096 Feb 23 09:25 conf
drwxrwxr-x 2 dinesh eng   4096 Apr  3 01:34 SCCS
drwxrwxr-x 4 dinesh eng   4096 Apr  3 01:34 doc
drwxrwxr-x 5 dinesh eng  12288 Apr  3 01:48 lib
drwxrwxr-x 3 dinesh eng   4096 Apr  3 01:48 src
drwxrwxr-x 8 dinesh eng     79 Jun  9 02:58 BitKeeper
```

i want to select and delete all the junk information except for the name of the file in one shot from vim. How can I do it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey VIM support `virtual block mode`.

In which you have choice of columnar selection of data.

1: Open you file using `vim`, press `Ctrl+v`.

2: Select all columns you wanna delete and `press d`.

3:  To save file and exit press `:wq`

Answer (score 1):

Just select the block with `Ctrl-v` and delete it with `d`.

Answer (score 1):

With `:help :normal` and a simple normal mode command:

```
:%normal! d8W
```

Which means "on every line in the buffer, delete until the 8th WORD".

With a substitution:

```
:%s/^\(\S\+\s\+\)\{8}
```

Which means "substitute every sequence of height groups made of one or more non-whitespace characters followed by one or more white-space characters, starting from the beginning of the line".

Answer (score 0):

Give the following command:

```
:1,$s/.* //g
```

Comment: this is a great answer, but it doesn't work properly for the symbolic links in his example nor for filenames with embedded spaces

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. The requirement to do the entire operation in one command is a bit high. One can go to the first line and give command 8dW. That does the job for one line. Then keep on going down one line at a time and press . (period).

Comment: Actualy it isn't. command should be like this:       :%s/^.{44}//

Comment: BTW: why not do "ls -1" in the first place?